# Is 33 MHs normal for 2 X R9 280x?

Tags: mining, hashrate

Eventhough some similar questions have been asked, none of those I found seem applicable to my situation.

I have two R9 280x's that together produce only 33 MHs (Windows 7, Catalyst 15.7). I know that the growing DAG files causes the AMD cards to gradually mine slower over time, but this still seems awfully slow to me when compared with what others report.

The benchmark option (`ethminer.exe -G -M`) returns:

> min/mean/max: 52.2/52.6/52.9 MH/s
>   inner mean: 35 MH/s

Now, can anyone explain to me what the '**inner mean**'?, and how it differs from the regular mean? Do the values above tell me that I can expect 35 MHs or 52 MHs? What would you say is a respectable hashrate for my setup? According to sites like http://www.mininghwcomparison.com/list/index.php?brand=amd it should be at least 40 Mhs.

edit: I would really like an answer here guys!

Comment: Did you installed Blockchain drivers? Did you flashed bios?